# Selective keyboard failure windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10

the following keys function normally: escape, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, prtsc, delete, home, end, pgup, pgdn, backspace, numlock, tab, capslock, enter, shift, ctrl, fn, windowskey, alt, left arrow, up arrow, down arrow, right arrow, ins

additionally all keyboard shortcuts function, which means it must be able to sense the rest somehow but seemingly ignores them when typing

---

it seems to be anecdotally linked to postponing a pending update; as it has happened three times and each time i have eventually given up and attempted a reboot only to see the update install itself and the problem vanish??

---

i have tried using a usb keyboard and the same issues apply.

the onscreen keyboard bypasses the problem but obviously can't be considered anything like a real solution, it does at least let me save my work(though i'd hate to type more than a sentence with it) and run simple tests.

i have not made any notable hardware or software changes in the recent past, nothing can be linked to this suddenly appearing that i am aware of.

anecdotally, the problem hasn't been seen to occur until the computer has been on and in use for some amount of time, having annoyingly and potentially disastrously(i wasn't doing anything important yet but it's only a matter of time until it happens while i'm in some timed test or need to submit something online rather than just save it to wordpad) appeared only when I am in the middle of something, though again no common link i can think of(once while simply browsing internet(chrome), once when typing an essay in wordpad with airplane mode on and all other windows closed, once while playing a game on steam).
I'd estimate that I properly shut down my computer roughly once a week (if not more often) so it doesn't feel like it should be an uptime issue? (seems to appear a few hours into that specific use of the computer, though this is often having turned it on from hibernation or even sleep so not sure where to start counting)

what it is not: windows key stuck (physically or otherwise), any keyor set of keys physically stuck, stickykeys, togglekeys, etc.
(the shortcuts do not happen unless I actually press winkey/ctrl/etc, otherwise pressing a button simply leads to nothing. eg p does nothing, ctrl lights up on the onscreen keyboard, ctrl+p prints)

---

am using an hp laptop

---

edit- 6/11: happened again, and again there was a pending windows update downloaded and waiting for permission to restart. i last turned my computer off three days ago and the keyboard didn't stop working until about 8 hours after i used pro to delay the update's mandatory restart by one week (upon restarting to fix the keyboard it of course took the opportunity to install said 'delayed' update despite this)

Comment: Perhaps it could be a driver issue? Try manually updating your keyboard drivers, or perhaps downloading the official ones from the keyboard manufacturer. It might be a problem with your operating system, which a reinstall could potentially solve as well. Dust in the usb port could also be doing this, and you could blow into it, or use compressed air if you're concerned about saliva entering the port. Could it potentially be some error with your function keys or function lock?

Comment: thanks for the reply, it isn't dust in the usb since it happens on the built in keyboard as well as a usb one, but I'll try the drivers.  -edit- there isn't any update when i say to check automatically, but i'll go to the website and try a manual one, will message back if the problem returns afterwards